# Regex for 1 or 2 or 3 decimal number, no leading zeros, precision 2 and fractions are allowed

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a regex which meets the following:

1. One or two or three decimal number.
2. No leading zeros inside the decimal number.
3. Precision 2.
4. **Proper Fractions are allowed (0.__ numbers).**
5. No text before the decimal number

Regex should match the following:

- 123.45
- 103.67
- 100.45
- 25.68
- 5.97
- 1.05
- 23.07
- 187.08
- **0.26**

The regex should not match the following:

- .45
- 1234.45
- 023.45
- 03.67
- 845.7

I came up with the following regex:

```
(?<!.)^([1-9][0-9]{0,2}\.[0-9][0-9])$
```

It meets all of the above *except* fractions.

I don't want leading zeros in case the decimal number has 2 or 3 digits. However, in case it`s proper fraction, I do want 0.__ to be allowed).

However, my regex does not match "0.__" decimal numbers because it expects the number to start with 1 due to "`^[1-9]`".

Please advise how can I modify my regex to match also "0.__" numbers.

Comment: What does "one two or three decimal numbers" mean? Or rather, how does it fit with "precision 2"?

Comment: @Qwerty What is `(?<!.)` supposed to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this regex.

```
\b(?!0\d{1,2}\.)\d{1,3}\.\d{2}\b
```

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pT4tM5/17#python)

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
\b(0|[1-9]\d{0,2})\.\d{2}\b
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/sN8bE9/1) you can see that it matches exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?!0+[1-9])\d{1,3}\.\d{2}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qQ4dB4/1)

`(?!0+[1-9])` is a negative lookahead that will stop leading zeroes in the number.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using re.match, here's the shortest you can use:

```
(?!0)\d{1,3}\.\d{2}
```

If you are using search:

```
^(?!0)\d{1,3}\.\d{2}$
```

You don't need to treat the first number differently, so you can use \d (which is the same as [0-9]) and make sure the first character is not 0 with a negative lookahead (?!0).