# Regex to match non-negative numbers, no leading zeros, 2 decimal places, at least 1 digit, optional decimal

Tags: regex

Same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141908/regex-for-1-or-2-or-3-decimal-number-no-leading-zeros-precision-2-and-fraction) except I **do not want** to allow **proper** fractions (ie. numbers less than 1, like 0.45).

I have this, which seems to work, but can it be improved?

```
^([1-9]|[1-9]\d)(\.?\d?\d?)$
```

[These tests](https://regex101.com/r/OMQm2u/1) seem to verify that it works, but I'm a bit rusty with regex, so am not entirely convinced even by the unit tests!

I think that I am looking for whole numbers or decimals that are >= 1.

Apologies but it seems the 12 unit tests I linked to got deleted :(

Comment: 0.45 is larger than 0

Comment: @AdrianShum well spotted. I said less than 0 but I meant less than 1. Fixed now.

Comment: ...why not just try to cast the string to a `float` and then (if successful) see if the resulting float is positive? Regexes and hammers, man...

Comment: @JackManey Oh I wish that was an option, believe me!  This is a stupid bug in Angular2 template-forms when you have an input control with min=1...the user can still type values less than 1 and Angular2 still marks the field as valid. I cannot clear that without the overhead of creating a model-driven form (which I don't want or need).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `^[1-9]\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?$` does the work

See test on https://regex101.com/r/Z1CaJq/1
(the test is using 3 decimal places, but idea still holds)

A brief explanation: For any number larger or equals than 1, it will begin with non-zero number, follow by any number.

```
^                           Start of line
 [1-9]                      non-zero number
      \d*                   any number of digits
         (?:         )?     non-capturing group, which is optional
            \.\d{1,2}       a dot, then 1-2 digits
                       $    end of line
```

Comment: Awesome, this is way better than what I have...but what do you mean by a 'non-capturing group' ?

Comment: Although shouldn't it be \d{1,2} for up to 2 decimal places?

Comment: actually it has no significance in this answer :P Non-capturing group is just a group.  However, you will not be able to back-reference this (in same regex, or in substitutions).  It is simply my personal habit to make groups that not expected to be back-referenced as non-capturing

Comment: Thanks for the info. FYI in testing this seems that numbers larger than 1000 fail, even though you have \d*. Very odd. It so happens that I do actually want to limit to a max of 999, so it works for me (I left that requirement out, as it was not so important).

Comment: I have just tested in regex101 and number larger than 1000 works fine.  If you want to limit to max of 999.99, just change it to `^[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$`

Comment: Ok thanks, i've accepted this answer. It does what I need.